# Test sbt plugin

Tags: plugins, sbt

Writing my first plugin for sbt 0.13 and trying to follow https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing-sbt-plugins.html.
It all works as advertised until it gets to  step 5. It prints the message "Running ... / simple" and never moves on from there:

```
build/sbt -Dplugin.version=0.14.8
Detected CYGWIN environment
Reading sbt jar from: build/sbt-launch-0_13_9.jar
[info] Loading project definition from project\home\dir\sheep-metadata-plugin\project
[info] Updating {file:/project/home/dir/sheep-metadata-plugin/project/}sheep-metadata-plugin-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to sheep_metadata (in build file:/project/home/dir/sheep-metadata-plugin/)
> set scriptedBufferLog := false
[info] Defining sheep_metadata/*:scriptedBufferLog
[info] The new value will be used by sheep_metadata/*:scripted
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to sheep_metadata (in build file:/project/home/dir/sheep-metadata-plugin/)
> scripted
[info] :: delivering :: com.myco.sheep.sbt#metadata;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT :: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT :: integration :: Mon Dec 10 15:11:00 EST 2018
[info]  delivering ivy file to project\home\dir\sheep-metadata-plugin\metadata\target\sbt-0.13\ivy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml
[info] Packaging project\home\dir\sheep-metadata-plugin\metadata\target\sbt-0.13\metadata-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published metadata to myHomeDir\.ivy2\local\com.myco.sheep.sbt\metadata\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\jars\metadata.jar
[info]  published metadata to myHomeDir\.ivy2\local\com.myco.sheep.sbt\metadata\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\srcs\metadata-sources.jar
[info]  published metadata to myHomeDir\.ivy2\local\com.myco.sheep.sbt\metadata\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\docs\metadata-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to myHomeDir\.ivy2\local\com.myco.sheep.sbt\metadata\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
Running sheep-metadata-plugin / simple
```

The build of the main project works:

```
build/sbt -Dplugin.version=0.14.8 clean update compile
```

But when I try step 5 from the tutorial (i.e. run `scripted`), there are no error messages, but no success either - it just never terminates.

UPDATE: On Windows 7 + Babun Cygwin, I get no error message. On Linux, sbt complains about `plugin.version`, even though I passed that in as instructed.

```
[info] java.lang.RuntimeException: The system property 'plugin.version' is not defined.
[info] Specify this property using the scriptedLaunchOpts -D.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed / clarified / found workaround:

First, let's clarify that the `assembly` plugin referenced in https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing-sbt-plugins.html must be added to the `simple` project, not the main project.

Next, I gave up on setting the `sbt-assembly` version number from a command-line parameter and I just specified it directly

```
sheep-metadata-plugin\metadata\src\sbt-test\sheep-metadata-plugin\simple\project\plugins.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.8")
```

It would be good to know if someone figures out how to make the example work as documented in the tutorial.